# Unable to use REGEXP operator in System.Data.SQLite

Tags: c#, sql, regex, sqlite, system.data.sqlite

Suppose that I have the following table and data inside it:

```
CREATE TABLE urls (url TEXT);
INSERT INTO urls VALUES('https://www.google.ru/?gws_rd=ssl#newwindow=1&q=&safe=off');
INSERT INTO urls VALUES('https://www.google.ru/?gws_rd=ssl#newwindow=1&safe=off&q=1');
INSERT INTO urls VALUES('https://www.google.ru/?gws_rd=ssl#newwindow=1&q=2&safe=off');
INSERT INTO urls VALUES('https://www.google.ru/?gws_rd=ssl#newwindow=1&q=23&safe=off');
```

I need to select all records where URL contains non-empty query parameter (in this case it's all but the first record).

I'm using SQLite, so I decided to use `REGEXP` operator like this:

```
string sql = @"SELECT * FROM urls WHERE url REGEXP '\/(?:www\.)?google.+?q=([^&]+)(?:&|$)'";
var command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, dbConnection);
SQLiteDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
while (reader.Read())
{
    Console.WriteLine("Url: " + reader["url"]);
}
```

but it gives me the following error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException'
>   occurred in System.Data.SQLite.dll
>
> Additional information: SQL logic error or missing database
>
> no such function: REGEXP

Is there any way to fix it? If no, what can I do instead?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQLite doesn't have a built-in `regexp()` function, as explained in the [documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html):

> The REGEXP operator is a special syntax for the regexp() user
>   function. No regexp() user function is defined by default and so use
>   of the REGEXP operator will normally result in an error message. If an
>   application-defined SQL function named "regexp" is added at run-time,
>   then the "X REGEXP Y" operator will be implemented as a call to
>   "regexp(Y,X)".

I admit this it is unusual for a database to support syntax but not the underlying function. However, it should be easy enough to supply your own function.

Comment: How can I supply my own regexp function? Is there any implementation?

Answer (score 0):

The `regexp` comparison operator is not part of the SQL standard. It is an extension specific to mysql.

Probably you can just use like. This should do the same :

```
url LIKE '%google.%q=%'
```